# Find top 2 in columns of a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Undefined row to column, group by year and column
From this dataframe:

```
year  month  count  reason 
2001      1      1       a
2001      2      3       b
2001      3      4       c
2005      1      4       a
2005      1      3       c
```

Using this code:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["year","month",],values=["count"],columns="reason").reset_index().fillna(0)
df2.columns = [i[0] if i[0]!="count" else f"reason_{i[1]}" for i in df2.columns]
df2["count"] = df2.iloc[:,2:5].sum(axis=1)
print (df2)
```

to changing the structure of the dataframe become like this:

```
year  month  reason_a  reason_b  reason_c  count
2001    1        1         0         0        1
2001    2        0         3         0        3
2001    3        0         0         4        4 
2005    1        4         0         3        7
```

Then, Next i want to select columns reason_? that have top 2 higher value only:

```
find_top_two = [df2.iloc[:,2:-1].sum().nlargest(2)]
find_top_two
```

the output become like this:

```
[reason_c    7.0
 reason_a    5.0
 dtype: float64]
```

But, the expected output that i want is the dataframe should be like this:

```
year   month   reason_a  reason_c  
2001       1        1         0
2001       2        0         0
2001       3        0         4
2005       1        4         3
```

Can Anyone help me to solve this matter? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your code a little more will get your desired output

```
cols = ['year', 'month'] + df2.iloc[:,2:-1].sum().nlargest(2).index.tolist()
df2[cols]

Out[52]:
   year  month  reason_c  reason_a
0  2001      1         0         1
1  2001      2         0         0
2  2001      3         4         0
3  2005      1         3         4
```